# I want to create get methods to return raw bson documents from my mongo server,without mapping them to models with specific fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create an API which will return a mongo document from the server with a GET request. However, I don't want to map these documents to specific objects in C#, the structure of my data can change and that's why I'm using mongo rather than SQL.

I'm new to mongo (and c# tbh). I've tried to adapt this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to my needs but have got stuck when creating the Service. BsonDocument doesn't have an Id, so I can't pass in a specific Id and look for a match.

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MongoApi.Models;

namespace MongoApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ManagersDatabaseSettings>(
                Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ManagersDatabaseSettings)));

            services.AddSingleton<IManagersDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ManagersDatabaseSettings>>().Value);

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

ManagersDatabaseSettings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MongoApi.Models
{
    public class ManagersDatabaseSettings: IManagersDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string ManagersCollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IManagersDatabaseSettings
    {
        string ManagersCollectionName { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ManagerService.cs

```
using MongoApi.Models;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MongoApi.Services
{
    public class ManagerService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> _bsondocs;
        public ManagerService(IManagersDatabaseSettings settings)
        {
            //gets mongo connection string and database name from the
            //ManagersDatabaseSettings class which gets it from appsettings.json
            var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.DatabaseName);

            //uses the name from ManagersCollectionName variable, set by ManagersDatabaseSettings.cs, again supplied from appsettings.json
            database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(settings.ManagersCollectionName);
        }

        public List<BsonDocument> Get() =>
            _bsondocs.Find(bsonDocument => true).ToList();

        public BsonDocument Get(string id) =>
            //stuck with this line - bson document doesn't have an ID?
            _bsondocs.Find<BsonDocument>(bsonDocument => bsonDocument.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", new bjectId("56fafcadbb55200d003eb276"));
var doc = collection.Find(filter).First();
```

official document here: [Get a Single Document with a Filter](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/getting_started/quick_tour/#get-a-single-document-with-a-filter)